# Like Box for Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I would like the Like Box on our website. However creating this in combination with a group seems not possible.

Does anyone know how to create a Like Box for a group? Creating a page would make things more confusing and means double work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can make a Like box for a group.

- [I tried putting a group url into](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)
- [Like buttons work](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
- [As will a Facepile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/)

The Live Stream and Activity Stream, however, do not.

Good luck!